# Getting started with python, cannot get iterator working

Tags: python

I have the following code, and I am trying to find the largest prime factor of the number that is square rooted in variable a.  When I do some print testing, it doesn't seem my iterator is increasing.  The code just runs infinitely it seems.  Any tips? Am I missing a point where this becomes an infinite loop?

```
import math

a = math.sqrt(600851475143)
primefactors = [0]
i=1

while i<=a:
    if a%i == 0:
        if i%2 != 0 and i%3 != 0 and i%4 != 0 and i%5 != 0 and i%6 != 0 and i%7 != 0 and i%8 != 0 and i%9 != 0:
            primefactors.append(i)
            print(primefactors)
    i=i+1
```

edit: just realized my mistake of using a as both upper-bound and the test value.  Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: That super long if-statement can be simplified: `if all(i%x for x in range(2, 10)):`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that approach won't work, in general.

Comment: Try using a lower value for `a` to test if it's just slow.

Comment: Your code does not run infinitely, why do you think it does?

Answer (score 2):

a is 775146.099225, so `a%i==0` is never true, so even if your iterator worked (and it is working for me), you won't get anything added to prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is printing out your i variable at the end of the loop after you increment and make sure it increments.
Your programs should loop 775146 times. This could possible take some time. I would try it with a smaller number first and then see what happens.